# How to sort javascript array with multiple datetime columns

Tags: javascript

Given the following array:

```
var effectiveDates= [
    {
        actualDate: "2017-08-29",
        effectiveDate: "2017-01-01",
        time: "13:22"
    },
    {
        actualDate: "2017-08-29",
        effectiveDate: "2017-01-01",
        time: "11:33"
    },
    {
        actualDate: "2017-08-29",
        effectiveDate: "2017-01-01",
        time: "10:57"
    },
    {
        actualDate: "2016-06-17",
        effectiveDate: "2016-01-01",
        time: "10:26"
    },
    {
        actualDate: "2016-06-17",
        effectiveDate: "2016-01-01",
        time: "10:03"
    },
    {
        actualDate: "2015-12-03",
        effectiveDate: "2015-01-01",
        time: "16:54"
    },
    {
        actualDate: "2014-07-07",
        effectiveDate: "2014-05-01",
        time: "10:47"
    },
    {
        actualDate: "2014-07-07",
        effectiveDate: "2014-05-01",
        time: "10:41"
    },
    {
        actualDate: "2014-07-07",
        effectiveDate: "2014-01-01",
        time: "10:36"
    },
    {
        actualDate: "2014-07-07",
        effectiveDate: "2014-01-01",
        time: "10:36"
    }
]
```

I am trying to sort the data based on `actualDate` or `effectiveDate` descending (or ascending depending on the order) and then by the time (also ascending or descending based on the required order). The issue I am having is that the dates order correct, but the `time` property does not order correctly. I am using moment.js for the date and time parsing.

This is what I have attempted so far:

```
var desc = true; //false;
effectiveDates.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (desc) {
                if (moment(a.actualDate) === moment(b.actualDate)) {
                    return (moment(b.time) - moment(a.time));
                } else if (moment(a.actualDate) < moment(b.actualDate)) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (moment(a.actualDate) > moment(b.actualDate)) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            else {
                if (moment(a.actualDate) === moment(b.actualDate)) {
                    return (moment(b.time) - moment(a.time));
                } else if (moment(a.actualDate) > moment(b.actualDate)) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (moment(a.actualDate) < moment(b.actualDate)) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        });
```

For some reason, when ordering the data by `effectiveDate` ascending or descending, the `time` is ordered correctly.
But when ordering the data by `actualDate`, also ascending or descending, the `time` data is incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of calling `moment(a.actualDate)` a load of times, better store them in a variable: `aDate = moment(a.actualDate)` etc.

Comment: Your time comparisons are made in the same direction in both cases.

Comment: There is also no need to for the else.... you can just have one set and flip the -1 or 1 based on desc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues:

1. Using `===` to compare two `moment`s won't work; they'll never be equal. Moment provides a `.isSame` function to do this.
2. To parse the times, you need to provide a format string, in this case `"HH:mm"`.
3. The subtraction of the two times needs to reverse between ascending and descending. Just flip the order.

See a working version below, with comments indicating the changes:

```
function sorted(desc) {
    return effectiveDates.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (desc) {
            // Use .isSame to compare two moments:
            if (moment(a.actualDate).isSame(moment(b.actualDate))) {
                // Provide a format to moment so it knows how to parse the times:
                return moment(b.time, "HH:mm") - moment(a.time, "HH:mm");
            } else if (moment(a.actualDate) < moment(b.actualDate)) {
                return 1;
            } else if (moment(a.actualDate) > moment(b.actualDate)) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (moment(a.actualDate).isSame(moment(b.actualDate))) {
                // Reverse the order of the subtraction when sorting ascending:
                return moment(a.time, "HH:mm") - moment(b.time, "HH:mm");
            } else if (moment(a.actualDate) > moment(b.actualDate)) {
                return 1;
            } else if (moment(a.actualDate) < moment(b.actualDate)) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

Output of these calls,

```
console.log("DESCENDING:");
console.log(sorted(true));

console.log("ASCENDING:");
console.log(sorted(false));
```

is:

```
DESCENDING:
[ { actualDate: '2017-08-29',
    effectiveDate: '2017-01-01',
    time: '13:22' },
  { actualDate: '2017-08-29',
    effectiveDate: '2017-01-01',
    time: '11:33' },
  { actualDate: '2017-08-29',
    effectiveDate: '2017-01-01',
    time: '10:57' },
  { actualDate: '2016-06-17',
    effectiveDate: '2016-01-01',
    time: '10:26' },
  { actualDate: '2016-06-17',
    effectiveDate: '2016-01-01',
    time: '10:03' },
  { actualDate: '2015-12-03',
    effectiveDate: '2015-01-01',
    time: '16:54' },
  { actualDate: '2014-07-07',
    effectiveDate: '2014-05-01',
    time: '10:47' },
  { actualDate: '2014-07-07',
    effectiveDate: '2014-05-01',
    time: '10:41' },
  { actualDate: '2014-07-07',
    effectiveDate: '2014-01-01',
    time: '10:36' },
  { actualDate: '2014-07-07',
    effectiveDate: '2014-01-01',
    time: '10:36' } ]
ASCENDING:
[ { actualDate: '2014-07-07',
    effectiveDate: '2014-01-01',
    time: '10:36' },
  { actualDate: '2014-07-07',
    effectiveDate: '2014-01-01',
    time: '10:36' },
  { actualDate: '2014-07-07',
    effectiveDate: '2014-05-01',
    time: '10:41' },
  { actualDate: '2014-07-07',
    effectiveDate: '2014-05-01',
    time: '10:47' },
  { actualDate: '2015-12-03',
    effectiveDate: '2015-01-01',
    time: '16:54' },
  { actualDate: '2016-06-17',
    effectiveDate: '2016-01-01',
    time: '10:03' },
  { actualDate: '2016-06-17',
    effectiveDate: '2016-01-01',
    time: '10:26' },
  { actualDate: '2017-08-29',
    effectiveDate: '2017-01-01',
    time: '10:57' },
  { actualDate: '2017-08-29',
    effectiveDate: '2017-01-01',
    time: '11:33' },
  { actualDate: '2017-08-29',
    effectiveDate: '2017-01-01',
    time: '13:22' } ]
```

**UPDATE**

A simpler comparator function:

```
function sorted(desc) {
    return effectiveDates.sort(function (a, b) {
        // Combine the date and time and parse them together.
        var ret = moment(a.actualDate + " " + a.time) - moment(b.actualDate + " " + b.time);

        // Flip the sign if we're sorting descending.
        if (desc) {
            ret *= -1;
        }

        return ret;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
return (moment(b.time) - moment(a.time));
```

Use:

```
moment(a.time, "HH:mm") - moment(b.time, "HH:mm")
```

You need to tell moment.js that the input strings are "time" strings.